# Set one year before start date

Tags: java

I use this this configuration in order to get the current date:

```
LocalDateTime start_date = LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC());
LocalDateTime end_date = LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC());
```

How I can set start_date to be one year behind?

Comment: You start by **reading the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), to see if there is a method that would be good for what you want to do. *Hint: There is.*

Comment: try LocalDateTime start_date = LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC()).withYear(Year.now().getValue()-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class has a [`minusYears()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#minusYears-long-) method which:

> Returns a copy of this `LocalDateTime` with the specified number of years subtracted.

You can simply do:

```
LocalDateTime end_date = LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC());
LocalDateTime start_date = end_date.minusYears(1);
```

Which (When run when this answer was posted) produces:

```
2018-02-07
```

Comment: Would be better to write `endDate = LocalDateTime.now(); startDate = endDate.minusYears(1);` so you don't call `now()` twice and get different time-of-day for the two values.